# Reattach fragment in onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment with 3 buttons attached to an activity class called `MainActivity`. When the user clicks on first button, an another activity is called using `startActivityForResult()`. In this second activity, user can select some displayed files. After selecting, once the user clicks `Done`, the user is taken back to the original fragment with 3 buttons.
I call `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` in `MainActivity` so that the call gets transferred to `onActivityResult()` of the fragment.

In the fragment's `onActivityResult()` I receive all the selected files. I zip them and calculate the size of this zip file. If the size is greater than the predefined size, I show an alert to the user, and when the user clicks `OK`, I again call the file selection activity using `startActivityForResult()`.

But in the `onClick` event of the `AlertDialog`, I get an exception saying `fragment not attached to activity`. The fragment is rendered fine, so how come it is not attached to the activity ?

Below are the relevant code snippets:

Fragment's `onActivityResult`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("HF", "OAR");
    if (requestCode == SELECT_FILES) {    
        ... code to zip the file

        int size = getFileSize();
        if (fileName != null && new File(fileName).length() > size) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("Error")
                .setMessage("The message")
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (isAdded())
                            startFileBrowser();
                        else {
                            Log.d("HF", "not attached");
                        }
                    }
                })
                .show();
        }
    }
}
```

This method launches the file browser activity:

```
private void startFileBrowser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, FileBrowserActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_FILES);
}
```

`ClickListener`of the button in the fragment:

```
selectFilesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (commonMethods.shouldBeActive(R.id.select_printer_id)) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(getString(R.string.file_replace_title))
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.file_replace_message))
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.continue_string, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        startFileBrowser();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   }
                })
                .show();
        } else
            startFileBrowser();
    }
});
```

My `onAttach` method in the fragment:

```
private Activity activity;
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    if (context instanceof Activity){
        Log.d("HF", "OA");
        activity = (Activity) context;
    }
}
```

Stacktrace of the exception:

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment HomeFragment{19909} not attached to Activity
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:952)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:943)
    at com.package.HomeFragment.startFileBrowser(HomeFragment.java:305)
    at com.package.HomeFragment.access$000(HomeFragment.java:45)
    at com.package.HomeFragment$1.onClick(HomeFragment.java:119)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:161)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae, Bundle[{_o=crash, _sc=HomeActivity, _si=4833782661551315669, timestamp=1484755442671, fatal=1}]
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment HomeFragment{19909} not attached to Activity
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:952)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:943)
    at com.package.HomeFragment.startFileBrowser(HomeFragment.java:305)
    at com.package.HomeFragment.access$000(HomeFragment.java:45)
    at com.package.HomeFragment$1.onClick(HomeFragment.java:119)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:161)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- The ActionBar -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!-- The main content view -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The method that sets the fragments in `MainActivity``

```
private void setupFragment(Class fragmentClass, MenuItem menuItem) {
    try {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();    
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I call it like this in `onCreate()`:

```
setupFragment(HomeFragment.class, menu.findItem(R.id.menu_home));
```

Comment: If my memory doesn't betray me your fragment could have been re-created so it's a different instance that's been attached in onAttach than you attempt to show the dialog from (onActivityResult). Try adding the value of "this" (i.e. the fragment) to your logs in both places and see what it says :)

Comment: Why are you using `onAttach()` this way? You should just use `getActivity()` instead.

Comment: "I call super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); in MainActivity so that the call gets transferred to onActivityResult() of the fragment." Is this the only line in `MainActivity.onActivityResult()`? If so, this is a huge waste of typing because if you remove your custom `onActivityResult()`, the parent one will be called anyway.

Comment: Finally, which line of code causes the exception?

Comment: @JohanShogun Yes you are correct, the value of `this`changes in `onActivityResult`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice If I don't override onAttach and use `getActivity()`, I get an exception saying `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference` on the line `Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FileBrowserActivity.class);`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice In the MainActivity's `onActivityResult` there is a switch block for other cases that are handled in a different way.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice For the code mentioned in the question, I get the exception at `startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_FILES);`

Comment: How do you add the Fragment to MainActivity? Is it static in main_activity.xml or are you using FragmentManager? Please show the relevant code that does this.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have added the relevant code.

Comment: If you're operating on a different fragment in onActivityResult then you need to ask your new fragment or the activity to perform the action (any other changes will be incorrect and hacky). I would personally prefer to ask the Activity since you already store a reference to it (just make sure you make it weak).  Consider the following pattern: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: The reason getActivity is giving you errors is that you're operating in an unattached fragment. You should avoid operating in unattached fragments, as that will hold the view hierarchy in RAM unnecessarily (and it's just plain messy). The reason your fragment is unattached "all of a sudden" is that your dialog stores a reference to your fragment through the anonymous inner classes and then executes code on it. As stated above, either show the dialog from your new fragment / activity or supply a callback to it (which you may want to define either as an interface or a static inner class).

Comment: @JohanShogun I understand what you mean. But I am showing the same fragment on `onActivityResult`. The instance is different as per my understanding. Do I still need an interface for reattaching it to the activity?

Comment: You shouldn't re-attach your fragment to the activity, you've been given a new instance. The reason you're operating on the old one is that your dialog holds a reference to it (your OnClickListeners hold an implicit reference to the old fragment since they're anonymous inner classes). Your easiest way forward is to make a callback to the activity in onActivityResult which displays the alert dialog.

Comment: @JohanShogun Thanks for the idea. I created an interface in the fragment and the activity implements it. This method in the activity is called from fragment's `onActivityResult`. The method shows an alert and on the click of the alert button, I launch the same fragment. I also add an argument in the bundle. So in the fragment's `onResume` I check for this argument and if it's present I call the other activity using `startActivityForResult`. It is working fine currently, but is the approach correct?

Comment: Sounds good to me apart from that you should check your bundle in onCreate not onResume if you're creating a new fragment :). Also, consider if you can just ask your fragment manager for the current fragment and call it directly without having to re-create it.